# How can I stop the notification FLAG_INSISTENT after 5 min?

Tags: android, flags, notification-channel

I am setting the `FLAG_INSISTENT` to my notification to repeat the sound of the notification. My problem is that I do not know how to stop the sound after five minutes to save batteries.

I already tried to cancel the notification, but there the user will not see the notification after that.

This is how I add the `FLAG_INSISTENT`:

```
Notification note = mBuilder.builder();
note.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
mNotifM.notify(AppConfig.NOTIFICATION_ID, note);
```

I already had the idea to cancel the notification after five minutes and creating a new one with no vibration and sound. Is there any other possibility to stop the sound after five minutes?

Comment: Have you tried republishing the same notification id but without that flag?  Sending a new notification with the same id  is supposed to update the old one.

Comment: `I already had the idea to cancel the notification after five minutes and creating a new one with no vibration and sound. Is there any other possibility to stop the sound after five minutes?` - This is the idea that I had in my mind too. I think you can go for it.